# Python module variables into current workspace

Tags: php, python, matlab, import

As I've mentioned before I originally came from a Matlab background and then moved onto PHP before discovering Python. In both Matlab and PHP there were ways to create a scripts that when run all the variables got dumped into your current workspace. That workspace in Matlab being the interpreter when called from there or the function's workspace when called from a function. I would use this capability for constants - for example, plotting tools where you want to define a set of default fonts, line widths, etc.

Now in Python I can import a module but then all of the references constants in that module require either `from {module} import *` or `{module}.{constant}`.

This doesn't really limit me it is just an inconvenience. However, it would be nice to be able to import a constants file and just have the constants available to whatever called them.

I suspect Python does not allow this but I thought I would ask to see if someone had a clever work around.

Comment: `from module import *` does exactly what you are asking ... its just a little different ...

Comment: Yep, I think so. I'd seen lots of comments regarding the pythonic way being explicit and lot of people saying not use `from module import *`. However, I'd never seen an explanation as to why that was bad. Is it simply that you dump a bunch of stuff the next coder will have to dig up? Or is there something inherent to the language that makes it problematic from a hard to track down bug standpoint or something else.

Comment: The point is to avoid collisions.  For example, both the python standard library and numpy have `sum`.  However, the functions are not identical.  By doing `from numpy import *`, you are replacing the built-in `sum` with the numpy one.

Comment: The point is to avoid collisions.  For example, both the python standard library and numpy have `sum`.  However, the functions are not identical.  By doing `from numpy import *`, you are replacing the built-in `sum` with the numpy one.  If you make a Matlab function called `sum` the same thing happens¸ but the python namespace system allows you to use both versions (or as many as you want).  You hear sometimes about some new, internal Matlab function being added that collides with a pre-existing user function, leading to breakage when Matlab is updated.  The python recommendation avoids this.

Comment: Yeah, I'd read about avoiding collisions and that is certainly good practice. However, for a standard set of directory constants for code only I will ever maintain it is much easier for me to read and write it with these constants just in the workspace. Yes, Matlab had that potential issue. However, I used it for nearly 10 years without knowing anyone who ever had a significant issue with that.

Comment: As a follow on, I'd seen comments that the best practice was to use 'import {package}' followed by 'from {package} import {module}' rather than simply using 'import {package}.{module}'. However, I've never seen that explained.

Comment: If you never ever import any modules from third parties, even the python standard library, then it might be okay.  But you are going to be doing a lot of reinventing the wheel that way.  There is a reason even Matlab has added an import mechanism (although it is still fairly limited).

As for `from {package} import {module}` (or `from {package} import {module1}, {module2}, {module3}, {etc}`), what is your question?  You don't need to do `import {package}` first, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, I know I didn't need to use 'import {package}' first but I'd read somewhere here on SO that using it first followed by 'from ... import ...' was the best method. But I never found any explanation as to why that would be superior to simply using 'from ... import ...' in the first place. Is it better or was that just that particular commenter's opinion?

Comment: I use other libraries all the time but I don't use `from {package} import *` with them. Only with my configuration scripts. Although, I have found lots of examples for SQLAlchemy that use `import *`. I thought the official docs used `import *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something you should normally be doing just to save a little typing, but here's one way you can do it:

```
# define some constants
PI = 3.1415927
ANSWER = 42
UNLUCKY = 13

# put them into __main__ module (your interactive session)
if __name__ != "__main__":
    import sys as _sys
    _sys.modules["__main__"].__dict__.update(
        dict((k, v) for (k, v) in globals().iteritems() if not k.startswith("_")))
```

Comment: Primarily I'd be using this to inject constants into other scripts not the interpreter.

Comment: That's tougher, because there's no way to tell what module is importing yours, and in fact the second and subsequent ones won't actually run it at all (using the cached copy instead), although you could work around that too if you tried hard enough. `from foo import *` is it, then.

Comment: Hmm... Not the end of the world. OK if there isn't any other way around it then I guess I create a couple of new file templates that just start with the necessary imports followed by the from ... * line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but maybe your IDE can help you to get rid of those imports. For example, in Spyder you can execute a startup script that will run when a new console is launched. Placing your imports there would provide direct access to those files.

Comment: I use Spyder primarily for my development in Python. It isn't as stable as I'd like - i.e. it stopped working on my Win 7 machine all together but it's a lot like Matlab. I know there is a place for a startup script - like Matlab had - but I hadn't tried it. I assumed it would work like a standard python script and any imports would have to accessed via {startup script}.{constant name}. If I turned these constants files into a package I could use the iPython > Startup settings to `import` and follow with `from ... *`. Seemed a little much to create a package or packages just for constants.

Comment: Indeed. I'm new at Python as well, propably there's a better solution.